# Script runs too long after emails already sent

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to have this code send emails faster and not hang up so much. Taking along time to end the script. How can I send the emails and end it quicker? That way if I need to send out more emails, it can run the whole script again.

```
function sendEmails() {

//Current spreadsheet emails are sent from
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Search Index").activate();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var RowCountEmailPresent = 0

for (var i = 5;i<=lr;i++) {
var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
if (currentEmail.includes('@')) {
RowCountEmailPresent = RowCountEmailPresent + 1
}
}
var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

//How Many Sends We have left
var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
if((RowCountEmailPresent) > quotaLeft){
  Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + "left and you're trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not sent.");
} 
else {

  for (var i = 5;i<=lr;i++) {

//What values are being placed in the email
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var ccmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var AlreadySent = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var currentStatus = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
      var currentOrdernumber = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
      var currentMon = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
      var code = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue();

//Actual email being sent to Reps and TLs
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{Order Number}", currentMon).replace("{Jep Code}", code);
      var subjectLine = "Offline Support - Order Status: " + currentStatus + " - Mon#: " + currentOrdernumber;
      if (currentEmail.includes('@')) {
        if (AlreadySent < 1){
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {cc: ccmail})
      ss.getRange(i, 3).setValue('1');
      }
  }
  } // close for loop


} //close else statment

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Congratulations, your email has been sent", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);

}
```

Comment: move your ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() and ss.getRange(i, 3).setValue() statement out of the loop statement.   get the values as array , and loop the array.   save the result in an new array and set array to the spreadsheet at the end of function

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I am still new at this, do you have an example of what you mean by that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See If this improves your efficiency.

```
    var AlreadySent = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      if (AlreadySent < 1){
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        if (currentEmail.includes('@')) {
        var ccmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
        var currentStatus = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
        var currentOrdernumber = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        var currentMon = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        var code = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
        var messageBody = templateText.replace("{Order Number}", currentMon).replace("{Jep Code}", code);
        var subjectLine = "Offline Support - Order Status: " + currentStatus + " - Mon#: " + currentOrdernumber;
        MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {cc: ccmail})
        ss.getRange(i, 3).setValue('1');
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the support!